# Rounding up in 0.05 increments

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I am looking to round up in nearest 0.05 increments. For example , if I have a number 1.01 , it must be rounded up to 1.05. Are there any python libraries that could be used to do this?

Comment: Isn't 1.00 closest to 1.01? Or do you only want up-round?

Comment: I want to only round up. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would solve this in the following way:

```
import math

a = 1.01
b = a*20
c = math.ceil(b)
d = c/20

print(d)
```

I know that rounding to the nearest integer value is easy to do, so I transform my number so that instead of incrementing by `0.05` I want to increment by `1`. This is done by multiplying 20 (as `0.05*20=1`).  I can then round my `20x` higher number to the nearest integer, and divide by 20 to get what I'm looking for.

Also note `math` is included in Python so no need to download a new module!

Answer (score 4):

A generic solution (without the need for `math.ceil()`)

```
def round_to_next(val, step):
    return val - (val % step) + (step if val % step != 0 else 0)
```

which gives:

```
>>> round_to_next(1.04, 0.05)
1.05
>>> round_to_next(1.06, 0.05)
1.1
>>> round_to_next(1.0, 0.05)
1.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```py
import math

def round_by_05(num):
    check_num = num * 20
    check_num = math.ceil(check_num)

    return check_num / 20
```

This gives:

```py
>>> round_by_05(1.01)
1.05
>>> round_by_05(1.101)
1.15
```